# How to have more than one compose key?

Tags: keyboard-layout

Currently I'm using <kbd>R-Ctrl</kbd> for the compose key. Under 12.04 I was able to set a couple keys to work as my compose key and/or to produce special characters (accents, ñ, etc.) but I don't recall how I did it.  Is there a way to make more than one key work for special characters and how would I set that up?

Comment: You want what key modifier and where?

Comment: besides R-Ctrl I want the windows key on the left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set more than one key as the compose key using `dconf-editor`. This is not installed by default.

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Navigate to: `org > gnome > desktop > input-sources` and edit `xkb-options`.

For example `['compose:ralt','compose:menu']` sets both the right-alt and the menu key as compose keys.

You can find the syntax to use for the keys by running `man 7 xkeyboard-config` in a terminal.

[image]

Comment: this worked, thank you! Sorry it won't let me vote it up...

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this let me using right super as a compose key when using an external keyboard; in addition to right ctrl (which I use on my laptop's keyboard, that does not feature right super).